# Using PHP-GPG with Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, public-key-encryption, gnupg, pgp

I'm working on an implementation, which should send every outgoing mail from my Wordpress installation gpg encrypted.

I built my small plugin with tutorial from [Tim Nash](https://timnash.co.uk/wordpress-pgp-email/), and I used the php-gpg lib from [Jason Hinkle](https://github.com/jasonhinkle/php-gpg). When I send an email from Wordpress 4.3, I get an pgp-encrypted mail, but I can't open it, because WP / my plugin uses the wrong public key. I checked it out, and pasted the right key in my user wp-profile, but ... nothing: wrong key. Have you any ideas?

```
<?php
/** @package    php-gpg::GPG */

/** seed rand */
list($gpg_usec, $gpg_sec) = explode(' ', microtime());
srand((float) $gpg_sec + ((float) $gpg_usec * 100000));

/**
 * @package    php-gpg::GPG
 */
class GPG_Utility
{

    static function starts_with($haystack, $needle)
    {
        return $needle === "" || strpos($haystack, $needle) === 0;
    }

    static function B0($x) {
        return ($x & 0xff);
    }

    static function B1($x) {
        return (($x >> 0x8) & 0xff);
    }

    static function B2($x) {
        return (($x >> 0x10) & 0xff);
    }

    static function B3($x) {
        return (($x >> 0x18) & 0xff);
    }

    static function zshift($x, $s) {
        $res = $x >> $s;

        $pad = 0;
        for ($i = 0; $i < 32 - $s; $i++) $pad += (1 << $i);

        return $res & $pad;
    }

    static function pack_octets($octets)
    {
        $i = 0;
        $j = 0;
        $len = count($octets);
        $b = array_fill(0, $len / 4, 0);

        if (!$octets || $len % 4) return;

        for ($i = 0, $j = 0; $j < $len; $j += 4) {
            $b[$i++] = $octets[$j] | ($octets[$j + 1] << 0x8) | ($octets[$j + 2] << 0x10) | ($octets[$j + 3] << 0x18);

        }

        return $b;  
    }

    static function unpack_octets($packed)
    {
        $j = 0;
        $i = 0;
        $l = count($packed);
        $r = array_fill(0, $l * 4, 0);

        for ($j = 0; $j < $l; $j++) {
            $r[$i++] = GPG_Utility::B0($packed[$j]);
            $r[$i++] = GPG_Utility::B1($packed[$j]);
            $r[$i++] = GPG_Utility::B2($packed[$j]);
            $r[$i++] = GPG_Utility::B3($packed[$j]);
        }

        return $r;
    }




    static function hex2bin($h)
    {
        if(strlen($h) % 2) $h += "0";

        $r = "";
        for($i = 0; $i < strlen($h); $i += 2) {
            $r .= chr(intval($h[$i], 16) * 16 + intval($h[$i + 1], 16));
        }

        return $r;
    }

    static function crc24($data)
    {
        $crc = 0xb704ce;

        for($n = 0; $n < strlen($data); $n++) {
            $crc ^= (ord($data[$n]) & 0xff) << 0x10;
            for($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
                $crc <<= 1;
                if($crc & 0x1000000) $crc ^= 0x1864cfb;
            }       
        }

        return
            chr(($crc >> 0x10) & 0xff) .
            chr(($crc >> 0x8) & 0xff) .
            chr($crc & 0xff);
    }

    static function s_random($len, $textmode)
    {
        $r = "";
        for($i = 0; $i < $len;)
        {
            $t = rand(0, 0xff);
            if($t == 0 && $textmode) continue;
            $i++;

            $r .= chr($t);
        }

        return $r;
    }

    static function c_random() {
        return round(rand(0, 0xff));
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: please provide your code (essential parts)

Comment: @m02ph3u5 I pasted the code yet.

Comment: this not your plugin code, did you already test with the latest master version?